# How to get the doctype declaration using DOM on Xerces 2.8

Tags: doctype, xerces

I am trying to add the DOCTYPE declaration to an output XML file using Xerces 2.8

I am using  DOMDocument* doc1 = implementation->createDocument();  to create the document

and I want to add the doctype from doc to doc1.

I could obtain the doctype from doc as follow:

DOMDocumentType* document_type = doc->getDoctype();

However, I can not pass document_type to the function createDocument().

Does anyone has an example of how to do this?

Thank you,

Gilmer

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler" property of your Xerces instance to an object of type "LexicalHandler". You will be informed about any events over the "startDTD" callback. This is at least true for Java. Should be identical for C.